# Android fast path audio loopback

Tags: android, audio, android-ndk, opensl

I'm trying to create audio loopback with minimal delay. Started with Android API using the AudioRecorder and AudioTrack, but the delay is too big.
Then I started digging in NDK and fast path audio using OpenSL.
But C++ is not among my strenghts. Still getting weird errors.
Is there simple working example of fastpath audio processing and playback - simple loopback?

Comment: _"Still getting weird errors."_ Noone is going to be able to help with those unless you specify exactly which errors you're getting and show the corresponding code.

Comment: Those error seemed undeterministic to me. What I realy needed was example how to use it properly.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

We recently updated the [native-audio sample](https://github.com/googlesamples/android-ndk/tree/master/native-audio) to toggle on fastpath audio when available.

[Feedbacks are welcome](https://github.com/googlesamples/android-ndk/issues/new) if you run into any issue.

Comment: Haven't noticed that. Thanks. I will take a look into it!